# Using PHP, MSSQL, Jquery for instant search

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

I am trying to implement an instant search function using PHP, jQuery, and a MS SQL database. I'm not sure what the issue I'm having is, to be honest. I'm not getting any php errors, and the only thing I could possibly think it is is that there is some confusion in connection to the database. I have the files on Windows Server 2003, and I'm attempting to access an MSSQL database on another server running Windows Server 2008. I'm completely new to these servers and to programming across them like this. (I'm an IT intern.) Here is the code I am using, it was modified from a tutorial for creating an instant search. This is the code I have at this point.

The PHP file:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['q'])) {
search();
}

function search() {
$server = 'Windows2008ServersName';
$con = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password')
    or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $server");
mssql_select_db('dbname', $con);

$q = str_replace("'","''",$_GET['q']);
$sql = mssql_query("
    SELECT
        db.First_Name, SUBSTR(db.Last_Name,1,300)
    FROM db
    WHERE db.First_Name LIKE '%{$q}%' OR db.Last_Name LIKE '%{$q}%'
    ")
or die ( 'Query Error' );

//Create an array with the results
$results=array();
while($v = mssql_fetch_object($sql)){
    $results[] = array(
      'title'=>$v->title,
      'post'=>$v->post
    );
}

//using JSON to encode the array
echo json_encode($results);
}
?>
```

The Javascript file:

```
var runningRequest = false;
var request;

//Identify the typing action
$('input#q').keyup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $q = $(this); //get the letter

    //if it's not a search term return false
    if($q.val() == ''){
        $('div#results').html('');
        return false;
    }

    //Abort opened requests to speed it up
    if(runningRequest){
        request.abort();
    }

    runningRequest=true;
    request = $.getJSON('search.php',{
        q:$q.val()
    },function(data){           
        showResults(data,$q.val());
        runningRequest=false;
    });

//Create HTML structure for the results and insert it on the result div
function showResults(data, highlight){
       var resultHtml = '';
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            resultHtml+='<div class="result">';
            resultHtml+='<h2><a href="#">'+item.title+'</a></h2>';
            resultHtml+='<p>'+item.post.replace(highlight, '<span     class="highlight">'+highlight+'</span>')+'</p>';
            resultHtml+='<a href="#" class="readMore">Read more..</a>'
            resultHtml+='</div>';
        });

        $('div#results').html(resultHtml);
    }

    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Instant Search</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
<style> /*css*/  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="">
        <input type="text" id="q" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

   <div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP is installed on the web server, but I'm not sure that it's installed on the MSSQL server, could this be the issue? I'm not really familiar with how the servers need to be set up to work with one another. Especially in a situation like this.

Comment: What does it do? If it doesn't do anything at all then you have an issue with your javascript.

Comment: this is going to take some debugging. if you put an alert() in the keyup handler, does it trigger? if you alert() your response from the PHP page, what does it display?

Comment: nothing on either count. Is it not accessing my PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you want the '$' on the q var in the javascript; it could be allowed (I don't think it is, but I haven't tried it), but it's not necessary and it is confusing.

There may be more but this leaped out at me as bad.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL, so I don't think I can use that fuction? I was under the impression `$q = str_replace("'","''",$_GET['q']);` would take care of it

Comment: hah missed that. yes you do not have that function for mssql.  The quote replacement is generally considered the simplest escaper for SQL Server.