# Jquery Keyup() example not working on server

Tags: jquery, windows-server-2003

I am trying to use the keyup function in a little search I made, but with the files on the server and accessing the page through IE8 and FF, the keyup function doesn't seem to work. To test it I borrowed the code from the jQuery websites example put it on the server (it's Windows Server 2003 R2). However, this example also isn't working(http://api.jquery.com/keyup/). I noticed it has the line

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/events.js"></script>`

and my initial thought was, "mine isn't working because I'm missing this events file!" but after googling I'm thinking this isn't the case. In my code I'm linking to a downloaded copy of jQuery, and I've also tried linking it through the googleapi's copy, no luck either time. Any thoughts about why the keyup function might not be working on the server?

Comment: Please provide a copy of the code you're using. JavaScript is executed in the browser, meaning the server is irrelevant (not including JS server calls, of course).

Comment: We can't do anything other than make wild guesses without seeing your javascript code and pertinent HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to post it again because I had asked a question about issues I was having before, here is a link to the javascript, html, and php in another question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324149/using-php-mssql-jquery-for-instant-search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code on that page seems a little broken. Specifically, it seems to use a `print` function that's absent from the latest jQuery (perhaps it's included in that missing `events.js` script?)

I've made some small changes to make a working version (note I'm using the Google-hosted jQuery; you can point that at your local version instead and it should still work fine.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
fieldset { margin-bottom: 1em; }
input { display: block; margin-bottom: .25em; }
#print-output {
  width: 100%;
}
.print-output-line {
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: monaco, monospace;
  font-size: .7em;
}

</style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="target">Type Something:</label>
    <input id="target" type="text" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
var xTriggered = 0;
$('#target').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
   xTriggered++;
   var msg = 'Handler for .keyup() called ' + xTriggered + ' time(s).<br />';
   $('#output').append(msg);
});

$('#other').click(function() {
  $('#target').keyup();
});</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this changed version, I'm using jQuery's `append()` function to output the debugging messages into a new `div` I've added below the text box. When you type into the text box, you should see the key press events being registered there.

Comment: Yes! this worked, I can't vote you up, but this tells me that it is working and there is something wrong with MY code:( thanks!

Comment: @dwf This may be a good time for you to find out about the Javascript debugging tools that are available for your favourite browser (typically the built-in developer tools in Chrome, Safari and IE, and the Firebug plugin for Firefox.) At the very least, learn how to view the Javascript error console in your browser to see the basic error messages that are being thrown out.

Comment: @dwf If the answer worked for you then you can go ahead and put a checkmark under the vote count. This will help the answer-er, and also give you some reputation.

Comment: Ok awesome, I enabled the built in javascript debugger for IE (I didn't know it was there) unfortunately that's what I'm using because that is what the company I'm interning with uses. And thanks @ShaneC I checked it!

Answer (score 0):

Does the element you're watching get generated dynamically, after page load? If so you'll need to use live:

```
$("#element").live('keyup',function(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
});
```

Otherwise try:

```
$("element").keyup(function(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
});
```

Also, make sure you are selecting the proper element (input box?) and double check the selector is correct. Some problems might arise in different browsers, handling e.keyCode, or not. The above example also checks for a key code value in e.which, if e.keyCode does not exist.